Convergent series with infinitesimal positive terms also convergent?
Assume $S_n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{n,k} < \infty$ for all $n$, $a_{n,k} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, and $a_{n,k} > 0$ always. Is it true that $S_n \to 0$ as well?
Counterexamples that I have found all involve negative terms somewhere.
P.S. This is a sufficient condition for a separate problem, if it's false I probably have to start from scratch

If you relax the assumption $a_{n,k}>0$ to $a_{n,k}\geq 0$ for a second, then you have the counterexample $$a_{n,k}=\begin{cases} 0,& n\neq k,\ 1,& k=n.\end{cases}$$ Of course you can modify this to get a real counterexample by adding $e^{-nk}$.

A template of some counterexamples: let $S=\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k$ be any convergent series of positive numbers and set
$$
(a_{n,0},a_{n,1},\ldots)
=\big(\underbrace{\tfrac{b_0}{n+1},\ldots,\tfrac{b_0}{n+1}}_{n+1\text{ terms}},b_1,b_2,\ldots\big)
$$
for each $n$.

An easy counterexample would be
$$
S_n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1n\, \Big(1-\frac1n\Big)^k=1.
$$
With a slight modification we can even get $S_n\to\infty$:
$$
S_n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt n}\, \Big(1-\frac1n\Big)^k=\sqrt{n}.
$$
